# Where to locate Python-3.6.1 interpreter in Pycharm on Centos

Tags: python, centos, pycharm

By default I had python-2.6 installed on my Centos. I installed python-3.6.1 and Pycharm IDE. When I open settings of my Pycharm I can't see new interpreter for python-3.6.1. How do I locate and add the new interpreter?

Comment: have you tried `which`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation based on Windows version, on mac is pretty the same, I'm not familiar with Linux version GUI, but should be very similar https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

In short, point to the Python executable by adding local interpreter in Pycharm project settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vFfv.jpg

Comment: I tried adding a local interpreter, but I can't locate the Python executable.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install python-3.6.1? Also, why not search for the `python3` executable? I don't specifically know about Centos, but on UNIX systems it could be in `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: My python-3.6.1 is in /usr/local/lib/Python-3.6.1.

Comment: I can use my interpreter through centos terminal but in Pycharm, In the list of interpreter I only have interpreter of python-2.6.

Comment: Have you checked this: [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html)

Comment: Oh and btw, even if your installation is under `/usr/local/lib` the python executable `python3` is usually under /usr/bin/ (afaik)

Comment: I did checked that link. It says I can add a local interpreter and add a Python executable. But the problem is where can I locate that python executable.

Comment: When I open /usr/bin/ I can only see python-2.6 and not python-3.6.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to execute `python3` from the Centos command line? Check `python --version` to make sure